# Creating Contract from Contract. Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address

Tags: solidity

I am having a problem with my smart contract making value transfers. My current environment:

```
Truffle v5.0.3 (core: 5.0.3)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.13.0
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 < 0.6.0;

contract ContractWallet {
    constructor() public{
    }
}

contract deposit {
    mapping (address=>ContractWallet) public users;

    constructor () public { }

    function testDeposit(
    )
        public
        payable
    {
        ContractWallet _newWallet = new ContractWallet();
        address(_newWallet).transfer(msg.value);
        users[msg.sender] = _newWallet;
    }

}
```

After creating a contract from a contract, I can not transfer ether to the newly created contract address.
I think I'll probably add 'payable', but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You need to add a payable external function in the ContractWallet declaration. `function () external payable { }`.

Comment: Or more likely, replace `function testDeposit` with this function.

Comment: I solved it after adding apayable external function in the ContractWallet.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add fallback function to your `deposit` smart contract like this:

```
function () public payable {
    testDeposit ();
}
```